# Search results showing questions without the searched for tag in results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search, caching

Recently, I was surfing on stackoverflow.com & I have found one bug in Question filter.

I was looking under the java tag and yet I saw questions which were not tagged java

[image]

The incorrectly shown question was [How to give the background-image path in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047364/how-to-give-the-background-image-path-in-css)

Answer (score 9):

The question originally had the java tag on it - [it was edited out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20047364/revisions):

> [image: revision]

It still showed up in the list due to caching.

Comment: Caching; Always caching...

Comment: @Marc The source of all evil.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn but without it everything would be really reallly sloooow.